# How to retrieve maven build number in pom.xml?

Tags: maven, docker, build-numbers, dockerfile-maven-plugin

I would like to retrieve maven build number in pom.xml so that I could use it to tag docker image with dockerfile-maven-plugin. I have checked out https://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html but that's not what I want. According to https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN8855 how do I get the build information to be used in my pom.xml? Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: If it is not the build number from the plugin that you mention, then what build number are you refering to? A Jenkins build number?

Comment: Maven build number, as in `maven clean install`. Does it generate a new build number every time it is run?

Comment: It does not, you need to use the plugin `buildnumber-maven-plugin` to have this behaviour

Comment: Could you show me which build number you mean, i.e. an example?

Comment: but buildnumber-maven-plugin needs SCM configuration which I don't need. I just build from my localhost, push the source code to github, build the image and push the image to dockerhub.

Comment: @JFMeier, https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN8855

Comment: So you mean a build number as part of the version number? Where is the build number defined? In your POM? Or is it supplied?

Comment: I expect every maven build would have a number and that's what I am going to use.